# Увеличение оперативной памяти при использовании контрола C#

Tags: c#, winforms

У меня вопрос, я поместил на форму контрол `ProgressBar` и сделал событие `Click` на Button при котором, увеличивается `Value` `ProgressBar`. При нажатии на кнопку растет `Value` у контрола и так же оперативная память приложения на 100кб за каждое нажатие
Довольно часто замечал, что память как то растет в моих мини-приложения

Вот код как использую это в статическом классе, при клике на кнопку просто вызываю метод

```
if (Main.Form.barProg.InvokeRequired)
{
    Main.Form.barProg.Invoke(new Action(() =>
    {
        Main.Form.barProg.Value++;
    }));
}
else
{
    Main.Form.barProg.Value++;
}
```

Понимаю что возможно такой подход не правильный, если не затруднит объясните пожалуйста почему и как делать правильно

Comment: То есть если нажать на кнопку 100 раз, то у вас выделится 10 мб памяти?

Comment: Если память растет, но вы не знаете почему, воспользуйтесь профайлером памяти чтобы узнать ответ.

Comment: @tym32167 _То есть если нажать на кнопку 100 раз, то у вас выделится 10 мб памяти?_ именно, но там не совсем по 100кб я так понял примерно от 50кб-100кб

Comment: Вообще, 100кб, это не рост, сборщик мусора рано или поздно освободит часть памяти. Другими словами, далеко не факт, что вся выделенная приложению память используется. Но попробуйте так `Main.Form.barProg.Invoke((Action)(() => Main.Form.barProg.Value++));`

Comment: @aepot ага, я так и сделал, увидел что каждый раз создаю новый `Action`, но раз если память будет освобождаться сборщиком, тогда я думаю проблема решена

Comment: Почитайте про сборщика, понаписано много всего.

Comment: Некоторые статические анализаторы кода указывают на явное выделение памяти с помощью `new`. | Если вас это сильно беспокоит, создайте обычный метод вместо лямбды.